# Converting every word or special character in a text file into a list?

Tags: python, list

What I have:

#text file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<script id="polyfill-script-bundle">
</script>
```

What I want:

```py
file = ['<!DOCTYPE html>\n', '<html lang="en" dir="ltr">\n', '<head>\n', '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">\n', '<script id="polyfill-script-bundle">\n', '</script>']
```

I plan to do this for an entire HTML text file, what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki partly but that question does not satisfy

Comment: how does not satisfy your question? you are storing each line as an element in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below retains the `\n` at the end of each line.

```py
with open("filenamegoeshere.txt") as infile:
    as_list = infile.readlines()
print(as_list)
```

**output**

```py
['<!DOCTYPE html>\n', '<html lang="en" dir="ltr">\n', '<head>\n', '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">\n', '<script id="polyfill-script-bundle">\n', '</script>']
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.split('\n')` sounds like the best thing here. Although be aware that this will remove the `'\n'`s, if that isn't a problem this should be your best bet.